# icons for templates Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: gnome, templates

I just installed Ubuntu 22.10 on a Lenovo T15 gen2. I put several empty LibreOffice and text documents in the Templates folder. This worked and I can now create New Documents by right clicking in a folder. However, the New Document types do not have icons, they would be faster to select if they did. Can I enable these icons somewhere?

Comment: I'm running 22.10 on the same machine (though the hardware in this case is likely not a factor), and I'm not able to reproduce this issue. When you say that you "put several empty LibreOffice and text documents in the Templates folder" are these files created by their respective apps, and do they show the correct icons? I ask because `touch`ing a file to create it, and then renaming it to a specific mimetype will not work (you'll see no icon associations).

Comment: that's odd. Yes I did make the files with the respective apps, and in the folder the icons show as they should, just not in the context menu:

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/OugQEf4.png